# In what situation will a NSZombie be created in an ARC environment?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, nszombie, nszombieenabled

In what situation will a NSZombie be created in an ARC environment?
That is, in ARC environment, how can an object be accessed or over-released after released?

Answer (score 2):

There is a good article on this matter that explains also how and why there may occure certain scenarios where in ARC the over-releasing and sending message to the released object can make things crash. https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-11-07-lets-build-nszombie.html Hopefully you will find an answer to your question.

"ARC has greatly reduced the frequency of these errors, but it hasn't eliminated them altogether. These problems can still occur due to problems with multithreading, interactions with non-ARC code, mismatched method declarations, or type system abuse that strips or changes ARC storage modifiers."